# Google App Engine source code not sync with Bitbucket

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket, google-cloud-platform

I made the connection between google app engine and bitbucket in google developers console and set up push-to-deploy according to the website: https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy

Jenkins is working well, but when I push my change to bitbucket, bitbucket code has changed, but Google Developers Console->Source code->Browse is not updated. I've looked at the commit history in google developers console->source code, it is also not sync with bitbucket. I have waited for a day, but it is still not upated.

My Bitbucket repo is private, but I think it should still work.

Is there a log that records the message between bitbucket and google app engine? I tried the monitoring->logs, but it only includes my application's info.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm new to app engine, so I don't know how frequent app engine should update from bitbucket... but it has passed over 20 minutes without an update. If I follow @jirugaray's suggestion of deleting the hook and re-bind the repo from app engine, it updates..

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I've had a couple of times where the bitbucket hook gets screwed up.

Please go to your bitbucket config>integrations>hooks 
You should see a hook with the url  https://source.developers.google.com/webhook/bitbucket?xxxxxxxxxxxxx

try deleting that hook, undo the binding from google the Google console and re bind the repo.

Comment: I tried that, deleting hook and rebinding. App Engine updated, but only one time.. not after other commits to bitbucket.

Comment: Basically, whenever I disconnect bitbucket from google app engine and reconnect, GAE will pull from the latest version, but not after further commits onwards.